# HP QC REST API for postman rest client

Tags: rest, api, postman, hp-quality-center

I tried to connect HP QC using postman rest client

The followig URL(Example)

http://qc-server.com/qcbin/rest/domains/DEFAULT_773497139/projects/773497139_DEMO/defects?username=username@gmail.com&password=mypassword

It throws error as follows

```
**Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access.**
```

when i tried adding the parameter login-form-required=y it goes back to login page how to store session and   fetch data through rest api using postman rest client.

Answer (score -1):

Choose Authorization type as BASIC and Enter credential and Click Update Request.

Postman snap:

[image: Postman snap]